# Multiple libraries using log4j

Tags: java, log4j, twitter4j

I'm writing a small Java application and having some trouble with log4j that appears to be caused by multiple, independent libraries trying to use it simultaneously:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.info(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger.info(Log4JLogger.java:85)
    at twitter4j.internal.logging.Logger.<clinit>(Logger.java:72)
    at twitter4j.http.BasicAuthorization.<clinit>(BasicAuthorization.java:43)
    at twitter4j.http.AuthorizationFactory.getBasicAuthorizationInstance(AuthorizationFactory.java:66)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory.getInstance(TwitterStreamFactory.java:121)
    at org.voltdb.twitter.drivers.Collect.main(Collect.java:13)
```

The two libraries I'm using are [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/) and [VoltDB](http://voltdb.org/). Both are in the form of JARs. If I use either in isolation, I don't run into this problem; both work fine on their own.

It would be acceptable to disable the log4j component of either library if this fixed the problem.

Comment: DLL Hell.......This is what OSGi was born for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a [reply to a Twitter4J logging problem that shows how to disable logging](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter4j/browse_thread/thread/3c14ce131f988863):

```
-Dtwitter4j.loggerFactory=twitter4j.internal.logging.StdOutLoggerFactory
```

Adding this property made the exception disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're using the right version of log4j as required by both libraries? Your error message seems to indicate in incorrect log4j version IMO.

Comment: oddly twitter4j seems to be using org.slf4j's nlog4j rather than the apache log4j http://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-core/pom.xml